# How to change the log level of a certain kubernetes component

Tags: juju, kubernetes

```
root@ip-172-31-19-242:/home/ubuntu# ps auxw|grep controller-manager
root      4278  0.0  0.0  12948   940 pts/1    S+   01:46   0:00 grep --color=auto controller-manager
root     29281  1.3  2.1 119116 82384 ?        Ssl  Jan10   2:59 /snap/kube-controller-manager/260/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr --master http://127.0.0.1:8080 --min-resync-period 3m --root-ca-file /root/cdk/ca.crt --service-account-private-key-file /root/cdk/serviceaccount.key --v 2
```

This was deployed by juju. How to change that "--v 2" to higher number?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the following config https://jujucharms.com/u/containers/kubernetes-master/78#charm-config-controller-manager-extra-args on the kubernetes-master charm?

Comment: Yes, updated the newest k8s charm and fixed it with: juju config kubernetes-master controller-manager-extra-args="v=4

Comment: If you've resolved your issue, why not write up your solution as an answer? Guidelines can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) That way others in the community could benefit from your experience!